# Find the angle x in the figure below

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference: In the figure , P and T are points of tangency . Calculate x. (Answer:$90^o$}

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas? I couldn't find a way

$PODT$ is cyclic

$\angle PDO \cong \angle DOT\\
\triangle POA :isosceles\\
\triangle OTB: isosceles$

$DO$ is angle bissector $\angle B$

DT = DP

[image]

Comment: Angles PDO and PDT are equal? Seems unlikely. DO bisects the angle at B? Is the curve APTB supposed to be part of a circle? a semicircle?

Comment: @GerryMyerson   Sorry;;my mistake...would be $DOT$

Comment: OK, but you still have DO bisecting the angle at B. And you still haven't told us what the curve is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Extend $AP$ and $BT$ to $K$. Then notice that $E$ is an orthocenter of triangle $ABK$ so we only need to prove $D\in KE$.

- Easy angle chase we see that $\angle PDT = 2\angle PKT$ and since $PD = TD$ we see that $D$ is a circum centre for $PETK$ so $D$ halves $KE$ and thus it lies on $KE$.

[image]

Comment: thanks for answer...Could you check if my resolution is correct?

Answer (score 2):

In this answer I assume that the radius of the circle is 1 and the origin is the centre of the circle.

Drawing tangents from the radiuses at $\theta$ and $\phi$ we get two lines ($DP$ and $DT$ in the diagram)
$$
\begin{align}
x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta&=1\\
x\cos\phi+y\sin\phi&=1
\end{align}
$$
Solving for the $x$ coordinate of the intersection of these two lines, $D$, gives
$$
x={\sin\theta-\sin\phi\over \sin(\theta-\phi)}.
\tag{1}
$$
The line from $(1,0)$ to the radius of $\theta$ ($PB$ in the diagram) has equation
$$
(x-1)\cos(90-\theta/2)+y\sin(90-\theta/2)=0
$$
and similarly the line from $(-1,0)$ to the radius of $\phi$ ($AT$ in the diagram) is
$$
(x+1)\cos(\phi/2)-y\sin(\phi/2)=0
$$
Solving for the $x$ coordinate of the intersection of these two lines, $E$, gives
$$
\begin{align}
x&={\cos(\theta/2+\phi/2)\over\cos(\theta/2-\phi/2)}\\
&=
{2\sin(\theta/2-\phi/2)\cos(\theta/2+\phi/2)
\over
2\sin(\theta/2-\phi/2)\cos(\theta/2-\phi/2)}
\\
&=
{
\sin\theta-\sin\phi
\over
\sin(\theta-\phi)
}
\end{align}
$$
where I have used the relation $$\sin((a+b)/2)\cos((a-b)/2)=\sin a+\sin b$$
in the numerator.

This is the same $x$ value as in (1), the point of intersection $D$, so the line $ED$ is parallel to the $y$ axis, and thus the angle of the line $ED$ with $AB$, the $x$ axis, is $90^\circ$.

Answer (score -1):

Extend DC and mark D' symmetrical D. M = $ DT \cap AB$. The triangle DMD' is isosceles and as DM = D'M, MC will be the height of the triangle DMD' and so we will have x = 90 degrees

[image]

Comment: How do you know that $D'$ is symetrical to $D$ with respect to $AB$. If that is true then you are already finsh. Your problem is exactly that, you have to prove $D$ and $D'$ are symetrical.

Comment: By geometric construction. CD = CD' = radius of circumference

Comment: You never use any data you have, so what are the chanses to be correct?

Comment: I didn't understand your observation...Symmetry is a subject of geometry and is part of solving geometric problems. Why would it be wrong to mark a symmetrical point on the line DC?

Comment: It is alright to make D' be a symmetric point of D about C. Creating point M is a further assumption such that CM is the symmetric axis. The question is "will CM pass through A, O, B?"

Comment: @Mick..you're  right..thanks